# Can I install a Windows 8 Pro upgrade in a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, virtual-machine

I bought a Lenovo 430K with Windows 7 Home Premium and upgraded it to Windows 8 Pro. I created a DVD from which I installed the Windows 8 Pro upgrade. I'm underwhelmed with Windows 8, however. I want to install Linux as the host OS and run Windows 8 Pro as a guest OS.

Will the Windows 8 Pro DVD that I created install Windows 8 Pro in a virtual machine, or would that virtual machine have to have Windows 7 installed first in order to install the upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. It's just that you still need a Windows license of some kind to "anchor" your Windows 8 upgrade.

In this case, you have the OEM Windows 7 Home Premium license that shipped with your computer. This license cannot be moved to another computer, but with linux as the base OS I believe it is still okay to use the OEM license in a virtual machine on that same computer, and therefore it can serve as the anchor for your Windows 8 upgrade.

Comment: He will be unable to install the `Windows 7 Dell OEM` license on the virtual machine.  So unless he has some other non-oem Windows license he wouldn't be able to install Windows 8 on his virtual machine and have a valid license per the user agreement.

Comment: @Ramhound you don't need to install Windows 7 to use it for an upgrade... you just have to be able to enter the license key during the Windows 8 install. The question is then whether it will reject the key at that time, and if it does whether or not phone activation will be able to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually install the upgrade over a preexisting installed virtual machine. For example, you could create a VM with win8-dvd and then install it again. I tried it, it works.

Comment: I am not sure this actually addresses the asker’s question: that was about using the DVD to install into a *new* VM, unless I am mistaken.